# Перевод строки в двоичный вид

Tags: java, строки

Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше очень длинную строку перевести в строку из битов?

```
String a = "a" String a_convert = "10101010"
```

Comment: @PauloBerezini спасибо большое, очень благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `Integer.toBinaryString();`